# An and statement returns True when it should return False

Tags: python, comparison

Im comparing two strings in an if statement, i expect them both to be False, but one is True.

See code example:

```
z = 'Test'
x = 'Test1234'

z and x == 'Test'
False

x and z == 'Test'
True
```

Why?
It's not possible that im the first person to see this, but i can't find other threads. I think im using the wrong search words.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `bool(x)` and you'll see that its True. `x and z == 'Test'` is the same as `True and True`.

Comment: `z and x == 'Test'` is the same as `z and (x == 'Test')`, not `(z and x) == 'Test'`, which you are mistakenly assuming would be equivalent to `z == 'Test' and x == 'Test'`.

Comment: Thanks, i get it now. Never knew operator precedence is a thing. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: You probably did (`x + y*z` is the same as `x + (y*z)`, not `(x+y)*z`), but didn't realize that `and` and `==` are also binary operators.

Comment: try asking better questions. "the language is wrong and it is not possible that I made a mistake" is basically what you write.

Comment: I did not, I never said the language is wrong, I ran into something I had no previous knowledge of, I got helped by some friendly people. Show me where I did wrong and help others improve instead of pulling them down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing a non-boolean variable in an expression is evaluated as a boolean which for a string is True if the String is not None and is not an empty string; e.g. bool('test') = True; bool('') = False; bool(None) = False.

By default, an object is considered true unless its class defines either a **bool**() method that returns False or a **len**() method that returns zero, when called with the object. See [built-in types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html).

```
z = 'Test'
x = 'Test1234'

z and x == 'Test' # False
x and z == 'Test' # True
```

The expression `x and z == 'Test'` using [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) is evaluated as `x and (z == 'Test')` -- adding ()'s for clarity. The lone 'x' is evaluated as a boolean expression so is the same as `bool(x)` so the expression then becomes `bool(x) and (z == 'Test')`.

This is evaluated as `True and ('Test' == 'Test')` or `True and True` or just True.